# Equivalent for jQuery's html() in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

```
<div id="block">
<p>some value</p>
<div>tons of stuff</div>
<li>etc</li>
</div>
```

In jQuery, we can do `var getHtml = $("#block").html();` but how can we do that in AngularJS? I only know we can bind using ng-model, but do we declare many ng-model on hundreds of HTML tags?

To clarify: I want to save generated HTML into my localstorage, I'm not trying to mix up AngularJS and jQuery.

Comment: First question you should ask yourself when using angular is, why would i want to access DOM elements directly? What is your goal here? If it's modification of views, it should be handled by modifying the $scope.xxx values of the view you wish to change. If you still want access, you can mix angularjs & jquery by doing a $("#someid", $element) inside your controller.

Comment: @MarvinSmit I want to store some value (html) into my localstorage.

Comment: You should only store data, not the HTML presenting the data (mix of data & template). *Unless the "HTML" is the content of a editor control (which would make the HTML the 'data').

Comment: @MarvinSmit I want to keep the format that's why I decided to store the html too. Imagine there are hundreds of line of data.

Comment: I think you should go read up on the MVC/MVP/MVVM patterns. Sounds like you are using angular because you 'have to', not because you see the benefits in the patterns being applied.

Comment: @MarvinSmit I'm half way of development, should I ask my team to rewrite everything? lol

Comment: Marvin I agree with you that it sounds like this goes against what angular is, but we have no idea of what the scope of his question is, so saying that using .html is bad without knowing more about the problem is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

According to AngularJS docs, you should be able to use html(), unless I am missing something?

You have to use the `.element()` function to get a jQuery or JqLite object:

`var content = angular.element('#fooid').html();`

Comment: Well I know that my answer probably isn't in the spirit of angular, but if you need to do something on the DOM, why not just use jquery, jqlite or the DOM ?

Comment: it's ok too to use javascript with angular, but it's overkill when u mix jquery with angularjs

Comment: I don't get it, why do you think that? It is sort of part of angular according to the documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element quote: `Note: all element references in Angular are always wrapped with jQuery or jqLite; they are never raw DOM references.`

Comment: Never said that you did :)

Comment: But really, you should be able to use jQuery with angular according to the docs. Maybe it is somehting else with your code, if `.html()` doesnt work for you...

Comment: do I have to include jquery.js to use .html()? or it's build in within angularjs?

Comment: It seems like you just need to call angular.element('#fooid') to get a jquery object, I will edit my answer.

Comment: With respect to the down votes, religion make people fundamentally irrational.  Just ignore them.  Nothing wrong with pulling html out of an element if you really need it.

Answer (score -1):

You can make a custom directive
try this :

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("myController", function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.text = "myText";
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.text = "newText"
    }, 3000);
  })
  .directive("html", function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        html: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(function() {
          return element.html();
        }, function(newVal, oldVal) {
          console.log(newVal)
          scope.html = newVal;
        })
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController" ng-init="test = ''">
  <div html="test">{{text}}</div>
  <div>{{test}}</div>
</div>
```

sorry for the first wrong answer :)

Comment: He asked for a way to get the element contents as a HTML string, not bind it to the DOM...